# Add Background Image While Hidden Tableview Loads Data

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimage

I'm pulling in an RSS feed and would like to have a background image while the data is loading instead of a bunch of empty cells.

While the data is loading I hide the tableview (not sure if this is the right thing to do for the time being) and I'm left with a white screen.  Is this white screen left over the UIWindow?  I'm just trying to get a better idea of what property or object I must modify to show an image while a tableview is hidden.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept here is to add a subview to the window property after the TableView, in order that the new view hides the Table:

In AppDelegate:

```
[self.window addSubview:tableView];
[self.window addSubview:imageOverTableView];
```

Then in imageOverTableView you can have a turning spinner while you're loading the RSS. When the RSS is done, you can animate imageOverTableView to disappear like:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.7];
imageOverTableView.alpha = 0.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

or simply `[imageOverTableView removeFromSuperview];` without animation

Comment: Ok, this TableView is one view in a tab bar controller, is accessing the window in the delegate the only way of doing this?